# how to wait for a device to complete last adb command before launching another one?

Tags: android, adb

I created an app that launch adb commands to a device and I need to wait until the device has finished excecute the command before launching another. Some commands have a wait option or produce an output i can read (so i know it is completed) but if I input a gesture like a TAP on something that makes the device process something for example TAP on an App icon and wait for the App to be open.

Is there a way to somehow know the App opening is completed?

Comment: I am assuming this is for system application .there is no callbacks but there are workarounds .for example taping on App Icon and check for current foreground activity or package name .

Comment: It is a windows app written in C# that launch ADB commands to a device via USB. The goal is to write scripts to stage devices.

Comment: you can poll 'adb shell dumpsys window windows | grep -E 'mCurrentFocus' to know if activity is opened .

Comment: Your issue will be easier to understand if you paste some code

Answer (score 2):

You can check the [logcat](https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/logcat) for messages coming from the APP you are waiting for.

Comment: I guess if i launch a thread to send `adb logcat -s "TAGNAME"` and listen to the right tags i might be able to know if the device has finished.